# How to return all child departments of child departments of parent department ? Weird I know

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I have a big app to build which should have a possibility for Admin to create a department and assign it a supervisor. Now, a department can be a child of another department but it can also be a parent of some other department. So a parent department could have for example 3 direct child departments, and each one of those 3 departments could have 5 child departments of their own etc ( unlimited many_to_many ).

Now a supervisor of the parent department must be able to manage all of his direct departments **and** all of the departments that are direct or indirect children of his department(s).

I am a "**bit**" confused on how I could retrieve all of this from my database for a given supervisor. I just need a general idea of how this could be achieved. How can I retrieve all of his departments and all of the child departments directly or indirectly connected with them?

I am using Laravel 5 for this project, just an info. Layed out a department_department pivot table for relations, as well as department_supervisor pivot for relations with departments and their supervisors.

Is the recursive function the way to go about this ? How to do it, since I am trying this and it is not working as it should.

```
public function index() {

    // get his direct departments of which he is a supervisor
    $supervisingDepartments = $this->employeeRepo->getAllSupervisingDepartments(Auth::user()->id);
    // get all the children departments of each of his direct departments
    $childDepartments = $this->getAllChildDepartmentsFor($supervisingDepartments);

    dd($childDepartments); // gives me only one item in the array, the LAST child department

    return view("super.employees.index");

}

public function getAllChildDepartmentsFor($supervisingDepartments) {

    $childDepartments = [];

    foreach($supervisingDepartments as $supervisingDepartment) {

        if( ! $supervisingDepartment->childDepartments()->count()) {

            $childDepartments[$supervisingDepartment->name] = $supervisingDepartment;

        } else {

            $this->getAllChildDepartmentsFor($supervisingDepartment->childDepartments);

        }

    }

    return $childDepartments;

}
```

Comment: Isn't it `1-m`? Can a dep be child of multiple deps? I suppose it can't and it's a 1-m relation. And for this I suggest `closure table`.

Comment: A dept can be a child of multiple depts.
A dept can be a parent of multiple child depts.
A child depth could also be a parent of some other dept.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on using closure table for this :) Got the same advice from a collegue developer as well. Used Baum package on packagist for my Laravel project :)